# When I remove error variable upload stops working

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

Uploading photos on Amazon S3.

In this form, everything works and the photos appear in my basket

```
s3Client.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({error:"Error -> " + err});
    }
});
```

But as soon as I bring it to this view, the files are no longer sent to Amazon S3.

```
s3Client.upload(params);
```

Help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: Perhaps the `s3Client` **requires** a callback. Try `s3Client.upload(params, () => {})`

Comment: @Phil Yes it worked. But why so, please explain? Why can't I write like that `s3Client.upload(params);`?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property), it seems only the `params` are required but that doesn't explain why it's not working. Very odd. I suspect the documentation is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) is missing a critical part. Other methods have this note...

> If a callback is not supplied, you must call `AWS.Request.send()` on the returned request object to initiate the request.

This caveat also applies to `upload()`.

So if you're not going to supply a callback, you need

```js
s3Client.upload(params).send()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "err" variable is part of its design wherein it catches the error in case there is a failure in processing the upload. If you are using a javascript framework, it has a documentation wherein you can see the purposes of each functions and what parameters it requires and how you should build a working prototype. Omitting some of the parameter will create an error if it does not match the method overloads in its component.

Comment: Looks like `s3Client.upload(params, () => {})` which is without an error will work. I think it expects a function as a second variable.

Comment: Is the function as the second variable required? What for? If nothing is transmitted to it and it does nothing

Comment: As long as it is not null it will work. Unless you cause some sort of an error.

Comment: I think the framework expects that when you code your upload function, you might encounter error during upload like network issues or corrupt file or unauthorized access, etc. The error variable and its error handling implementation is provided to cater such needs. If you want perform upload without relying on a javascript framework, then you can use a traditional way of uploading but it will be tedious. See the documentation of your js framework to see if it covers a method overload that not requires error handling during upload.